# Android app running when deployed via Android Studio but not installed on phone

Tags: android, android-studio

When running my app on my device straight from android studio, its running fine when deployed but its not actually installing - as in no icon in the menu etc (but it is in the settings under apps).  Any help to solve would be great. 
manifest is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co.uk.malleymob.morecheatsforsims4" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MainActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".generalCodes"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_general_codes" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".interactions"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_interactions" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".skills"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_skills" >
    </activity>

     <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".simCheats"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cheats" >
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to popular belief the action of this intent filter is not supposed to contain the activity's class name. This should fix it:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: this hasn't seemed to work am i missing anything else?  sorry for the dumb questions ! thanks again

Comment: This is the code that will add the app's icon (in this case link to `MainActivity`) to launcher. Just replace the intent filter you had with this one and look for `@mipmap/ic_launcher` icon with `@string/app_name` caption in the launcher. If it doesn't work try clean build and uninstall the app from phone first.

Comment: @PhilipS Then you may have a different problem. Please ask a new question and describe your problem as best as you can.

Answer (score -1):

It is definitely installed on the phone, if it was `run` on the phone.

You could try compiling the `apk` and manually installing with `adb`:

I assume you are using gradle to build:

From project directory root:

**View build tasks**:

`./gradlew tasks`
`./gradlew assembleDebug`

The `apk` would be created in `app/build/outputs/apk/`

Now `cd` to that directory and run:

`adb install my-app.apk`

Make sure your device or emulator is connected